# Colocar una imagen estática en un Django tempalt

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, imagen, static

Intenté utilisar un .png en un archivo base.html de un proyecto Django, sin embargo no se muestra sobre el sitio. Encontré una 404

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver arriba el logo .png que quiero mostrar y bien en la carpeta todo/static de mi sitio y sin embargo me da un error 404. ¿Necesito cambiar algo en la configuración del .py?

Aqui esta la parte relacionada en `settings.py`:

```
...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
...
```

Entonces, como colocando una imagen estática en un Django tempalt

Answer (score 0):

Tiene que poner primero el primer link rel tu icono para que te cargue en  tu base.html., en tu caso debajo del meta y te cargara. osea te doy un ejemplo como tengo yo un base.html django.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    {% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'images/image.ico' %}">
    <!----> <link href="{% static 'core/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"> -->

<!-- Fuentes -->
<link href="{% static 'core/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Estilos -->
<link href= "{% static 'core/css/business-casual.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">



`
```